# Does the RepairedOnMe command work? If so, what's the point of it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind, the-elder-scrolls-construction-set

One of the obscure *Morrowind* script commands is `RepairedOnMe`, which [the UESP documentation](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Tes3Mod:RepairedOnMe) says works as follows:

> Returns 1 if the calling object is repaired by given object, or 0 otherwise. For example,
>
> `if ( "banhammer_unique"->RepairedOnMe, "repair_journeyman_01" == 1 )`
>
> checks against a Banhammer being repaired by a journeyman's hammer. Obviously, the ObjectID should be a valid repair item and the calling item should be a weapon or armor.

Does this command even work? A [talk page user](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Tes3Mod_talk:RepairedOnMe) said that the example didn't work for them, and I don't have a Windows machine to test myself.

If it does work, what's the point of `RepairedOnMe`? Do any mods do anything useful with that call? None of the vanilla scripts use it, so I'm wondering if it does anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it was only for devs to quickly debug repair items and such without having to use them. Don't know if any mods use it.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenMW reverse-engineering effort describes [RepairedOnMe](https://wiki.openmw.org/index.php?title=Project_History#Version_0.46.0) as being broken in the vanilla game.  In OpenMW, it always returns 0.